# Yii chekboxes breaking array of HTML forms

Tags: php, yii

I have an array of forms for a list of accessories defined, in a simpler than existing form, like so:

```
echo CHtml::activeCheckBox($accessory, 'bidirectional[]', array('checked'=>$accessory->bidirectional));
```

I do the form building this way so that I can dynamically add new rows via jQuery without having to fiddle with index positions within all the elements.

The problem I am getting is that `activeCheckBox` produces two fields for the sake of setting `0` in the active record. This causes problems when I come to rebuild the form, due to two entries for this element I actually convert:

```
array(9) { ["bidirectional"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

To the latter entry having it owns row and so breaking all my programming.

Is there anyway to do dynamic indexes for lists of forms in Yii easily or do I have to go back to using static indexes?

Comment: Do you need `0` passed into your model? You can disable `uncheckValue` by setting it to `null`, as param in htmlOptions, ie: `array('uncheckValue' => null)`

Comment: @PeterM That's interesting, I never knew that, I think that solves all my problems thanks

Comment: @PeterM If you put something like that down as an answer I am willing to accept it, it did mostly solve my problem

Comment: Alright, added more explanation so others could benefit too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, yii activeCheckBox generates hidden input, so when submitting form value is always set. In your case hidden inputs breaks indexes.

To keep dynamic indexes hidden inputs should be removed. Drawback of this is that you no longer have "unchecked" value. To disable uncheck value, simply set `uncheckValue` to `null`:

```
echo CHtml::activeCheckBox($accessory, 'bidirectional[]', array(
    'checked'=>$accessory->bidirectional,
    'uncheckValue' => null
    ));
```